# Precision sum of doubles

Tags: c++, beginner

Summing doubles can cause a loss of precision.
Summing integers, however, doesn't. (Assuming no overflow.)

Here's a high precision sum function I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#define BASE 10

bool is_int(double n) {
  double intpart;
  return std::modf(n, &intpart) == 0.0;
}

double sum(std::vector<double> nums) {
  int n = nums.size();

  int maxepower = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    while(!is_int(nums[i] * pow(BASE, maxepower))) { maxepower++; }
  }

  int pieces[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    pieces[i] = nums[i] * pow(BASE, maxepower);
  }

  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    sum += pieces[i];
  }

  return sum / pow(BASE, maxepower);
}
```

I'm new to C++ so extra feedback on idioms would be helpful.

EDIT:
Example:

```
int main() {
  std::cout << 0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3 << std::endl;
  std::cout << sum({0.1, 0.2, -0.3}) << std::endl;
}
```

gives

```
5.55112e-17
0
```

Comment: I have some doubts that this is "higher precision" than then normal addition of doubles. A `double` has 52 bits for the mantissa, but `int` has 32 bit (on most platforms). As an example, `sum({M_PI, -M_PI_2, -M_PI_2})` returns `-2.14748e-07` which is quite imprecise.

Comment: It's only in some particular cases and I should have used longs but yes, you're right.

Comment: Could you add examples where your function actually does produce better results than plain addition?

Comment: I don't think this is a particular case, and even with `long` the `nums[i] * pow(BASE, maxepower)` calculation can easily overflow.

Comment: I *assume* that your code is meant for sums like `0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3` which give `5.55112e-17` with the "normal" addition. However, the reason is *not* that floating point addition is imprecise, but that those numbers **cannot** be exactly represented as a binary floating point number.

Comment: Jup, you're right. So it minimises representation errors?
Even if this is bad code, I've already learned from the comments here.

Comment: Here is another example: Even with `int` changed to `long` in your code, `sum({22222222222222., -11111111111111., -11111111111111., 2.222222, -2.222222 })` gives `-9.22337e+12`. Normal addition of those number (in the same order) gives the correct result `0`.

Comment: Wauw so it's not even slightly better? That stinks.

Comment: The best way to sort doubles is to sort them low -> high first then perform addition.

Comment: If you're interested in higher precision summations, take a look at [Kahan summation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)

Comment: Thanks! This was just a programming competition question though.

Answer (score 1):

It has a bug: very small numbers are completely ignored:

```
sum({0.1, 0.0000001}) -> 0.1
```

If technical limitations do not allow you to change this behaviour, you should:

- Document it in a comment as a know limitation
- Put a condition in the loop `if x < min_tolerance {fail}`, to adhere to fail fast fail loudly, instead of silently failing.

Comment: I'm afraid that's a limit imposed by how modf works. Is there a better way to heck `is_int`?

Comment: You could try checking to see if floor(x)  < x